# How can I delete Google Cache in Google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for Google docs that returns info from an outside API .
But my problem is that Google save Cache , so it doesn't update it .
My question is how can I delete **or** disable Google Cache?

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to avoid it, than to clear it. It can be done by adding an additional GET parameter with a random number. Just generate it and append it.

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://url.com/foobar?random=" + randomNum);
```

1001 means that the random number will be between 0 and 1000, adjust as needed.

Comment: http://api.craea.name/esim/military/damage/json/62/1?time=time
http://api.craea.name/esim/military/damage/json/62/1&time=time
this 2 urls don't work me with ur way

Comment: I had to make it "&randomNum"

Comment: @Aaron The idea was to add a random GET param, hoping that the target server won't hate you for it. In my example above, it was the only param I was passing, therefore it had a "leading" question mark, indicating beginning of GET query string.

Answer (score 0):

I talked with Digital Lemon and we do it like this:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
var dot = repeat('.', randomNum)
var text =    UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.craea.name/esim/military/damage/json/"+unit+"/1"+dot).getContentText();

function repeat(s, n){
var a = [];
while(a.length < n){
    a.push(s);
}
return a.join('');
}
```

And that worked. Thanks for your help.